# display posts of particular category from month archive link?

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

I am using archives by month, the output is like

1. september 2012
2. August 2012
3. july  2012

Ihat I want is, when someone clicks on september for example, he should see the posts which were published in september and were of category "A".

Comment: *Please tell me how to do it* isn't a good way to get an answer for a very broad question like you are asking. You would benefit from reading http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx which will help you to get good answers to the questions you post here.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has an excellent documentation on how o do all kind of things... If you're gonne loop through posts that you've called for you should use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) and then there is diffrent arguement for the function you could use that is explained further  at [wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) and to get what

Comment: i already have the functionality to display the posts by month , which is inbuilt in wordpress using archives , what i want to have is if someone clicks on that archive for a month , it should display the posts of that month(correct , its happening) but from only a particular category..(cant do )

Comment: if you go into the archive.php template file and add the arguement for month then it will work

Answer (score 0):

WordPress use  archives.php template file to display post of a selected month and to display categories use category.php page template file.
To display all post form a selected month and from specifies category you have to use [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries)

Comment: The selected month will be clicked , is there any way , i could get what the user clicked?

Comment: You could use this plugin to list all month http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smart-archives-reloaded/

Answer (score 0):

Tested: The following returned only the specified month sorted archives on archive.php:
Each month labeled buttons will link to the correct category based archive with [get_month_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link);

```
<a href="<?php echo get_month_link('2012', '10'); ?>">October 2012</a>
```

Refer to the Codex entry for the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display):

1. category-{slug}.php
2. category-{id}.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

So, if you have a category, 'lamps', with a category ID of 1, you could do either of the following:

```
category-lamps.php or category-1.php
```

And WordPress will use that template to render the archive index page for that category. 
Here is the date based archive hierarchy:

1. date.php
2. archive.php
3. index.php